# symbol 'T' is not resolved on the line after the template keyword

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to C++ but know majority of other mainstream programming languages. I've looked online for a solution to my problem but can't seem to find one. Here is some of my code so far:

object.h:

```
class Object final {
public:
    template <Component T>
    const Component& AddComponent<T>();
};
```

object.cpp:

```
#include "object.h"

template <Component T>
const Component& Object::AddComponent<T>() {

}
```

The issue is that symbol 'T' is not resolved on the line after the template keyword. I am using eclipse and the g++ compiler on linux.

Comment: Does your class declaration comply with [Classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes)? (also, bookmark [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/) -- it is one of the finest C++ reference sites available.)

Comment: The declaration and **implementation** of a template must be done in the header.

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: `template<Component T>` isn't valid, and `<T>` shouldn't be in the next line.

Comment: @eyllanesc: That’s not strictly a “must”, but it is what any novice should be doing.

Comment: What do you think `template<Component T>` does?  It **is** potentially valid in C++20…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in c++, the final keyword means that a virtual class method will not be overloadable by a child class, which is not how you are using it. This keyword should therefore go away.
Then, "Component" doesn't exist in c++. The way you're using it makes me think it is a typename, seeing as you are returning an element of type "Component". You should first define it or, if it is supposed to be a typename that varies for different calls of the function, it should be a template parameter.
You also shouldn't write "<T>" in the declaration of the function, as it doesn't make sense.
Last but not least, the definition of the function template should be specified in the header file, as it is required for instanciation.
The correct syntax should therefore be :
object.h:

```
class Object {
public:
    template <typename Component, Component T>
        const Component &AddComponent() {
            // adding component and return statement here.
        }
};
```

example main.cpp:

```
#include "object.h"

int main() {
    Object obj;
    obj.AddComponent<int, 4>();
    return 0;
}
```

object.h (if "Component" is predefined):

```
class Object {
public:
    template <Component T>
        const Component &AddComponent() {
            // adding component and return statement here.
        }
};
```

main.cpp (if "Component" is predefined):

```
#include "object.h"

int main() {
  Object obj;
  obj.AddComponent<4>();
  return 0;
}
```

Have a nice day.
PS: Sorry if I made any English mistakes, I'm French.